# When running a compiled pyd file with Cython, a "takes exactly 1 positional argument (2 given)" error occurs

Tags: python, pyqt5, cython, cythonize

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout

class ExampleApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # UI 초기화
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        # 버튼 생성
        self.btn = QPushButton('click', self)
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.on_button_click)

        # 레이아웃 생성
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)

        # 윈도우에 레이아웃 설정
        self.setLayout(layout)

        # 윈도우 설정
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('pyqt5 example')
        self.show()

    def on_button_click(self):
        print('clicked.')


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = ExampleApp()
sys.exit(app.exec_())`
```

test.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from Cython.Build import cythonize

ext_modules = [
    Extension("test", ["test.pyx"]),
]

setup(
    name='test',
    ext_modules=cythonize(ext_modules, compiler_directives={'language_level': "3"}),
    zip_safe=False
)
```

setup.py for compiling

```
__import__("test")
```

main.py

The above code is an example I wrote. After writing this code into a pyd and C file using Cython, I encounter a TypeError: on_button_click() takes exactly 1 positional argument (2 given) when trying to run the pyd file. I've made every effort to find the cause but couldn't figure it out. Does anyone know the reason? I am using Windows 10 64-bit, Python 3.8.10, and Visual Studio Community 2022.

I tried using Visual Studio 2019 for a different MSVC version, but it still didn't work. I also attempted to downgrade Cython, suspecting that it might be the issue, but that didn't work either. Although I haven't tested with higher versions of Python, I am using Python 3.8.10 because it needs to run on Windows 7.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractbutton.html#clicked) your `on_button_click` should accept a `checked` parameter.

Comment: @MichaelButscher probably not. Because when you run the source without compiling it with Cython (I mean running as a .py file), The issue doesn't appear.

Comment: @mahaha3211 That's because PyQt internally imitates the Qt behavior, which is capable of calling a function/slot with less arguments than the signal signature, and it simply does it with a basic try/except loop, which doesn't seem the case with Cython. Either add the argument, or use a slot decorator.